# Determine the range of $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ of a for a weighted convergent sequence.

Tags: real-analysis

Determine the range of $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ for which the following statement holds. If a sequence $\{ x_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ of real numbers satisties $\lim_{n \to \infty}{ n^\alpha \,\, |x_n - x_{n+1}|}=0$, Then it is convergent sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $\alpha < 1$ consider the sequence $x_n = \ln(n)$. Then
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }n^{\alpha}|x_{n+1}-x_n| &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n^\alpha \ln(1+\frac{1}{n})\\ &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n^{1-\alpha}} n\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})=0
\end{align*} but $(x_n)$ diverges.

When $\alpha > 1$ we will show convergence by cauchy criterion which is for a given $\epsilon >0$,there exist a $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\lvert x_m - x_n\rvert < \epsilon$ for all $m,n \geq n_0$. Wlog assume $m>n$. Choose $n_0$ such that for the given $\epsilon$, $n^\alpha |x_{n+1}-x_n|<\frac{\epsilon}{c_0}$ for all $n>n_0 \geq 1$ and where $c_0 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^\alpha}$ (It is well known that this is a finite number whenever $\alpha >1$). Applying triangle inequality to $\lvert x_m - x_n \rvert$ we get,
\begin{align*}
\lvert x_m - x_n\rvert &\leq \lvert x_m - x_{m-1}\rvert+\cdots +\lvert x_{n+1}-x_n\rvert\\ &=\frac{1}{(m-1)^\alpha} (m-1)^\alpha|x_m-x_{m-1}|+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^\alpha}n^\alpha|x_{n+1}-x_n|
\\ &< \biggl(\sum_{k=n}^{m-1}\frac{1}{k^\alpha}\biggr)\frac{\epsilon}{c_0} <\biggl(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^\alpha}\biggr)\frac{\epsilon}{c_0}=c_0\frac{\epsilon}{c_0}=\epsilon
\end{align*}

$\mathbf{Edit}$: I forgot the case $\alpha = 1$. When $\alpha = 1 $ consider the sequence $x_n = \sin(1/n)$. It is well known that $(x_n)$ oscillates rapidly as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Hence the limit does not exist. But,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}n|x_{n+1}-x_n|&=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n\biggl|\sin\biggl(\frac{1}{n+1}\biggr)-\sin\biggl(\frac{1}{n}\biggr)\biggr|\\&=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n \biggl| 2\cos\biggl(\frac{2n+1}{2n(n+1)}\biggr)\sin\biggl(\frac{-1}{2n(n+1}\biggr)\biggr| \\ &=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2(n+1)}{2(n+1)}n \biggl| 2\cos\biggl(\frac{2n+1}{2n(n+1)}\biggr)\sin\biggl(\frac{-1}{2n(n+1)}\biggr)\biggr|\\&=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2(n+1)}\biggl| 2\cos\biggl( \frac{2+1/n}{2(n+1)}\biggr) \frac{\sin\biggl(\frac{-1}{2n(n+1)} \biggr)}{\frac{1}{2n(n+1)}} \biggr| = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{2}{2(n+1)}=0
\end{align*}
because $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\cos(\frac{2+1/n}{2(n+1)}) =1$, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sin(1/n)}{1/n} = 1 $

Hence $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is convergent whenever $\alpha >1$

Comment: Thank you very much. But why did you use a certain sequence for every case? Don't we want to solve for a sequence in general?

Comment: @AliJoohy The statement in your question need not be true when $\alpha =1$ and $\alpha <1$, which I demonstrated by giving counterexamples. But the statement is true when $\alpha >1$ which I have proved by taking an arbitrary sequence.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome :-)

Comment: I think in $c_0$ you meant $k$ instead of $n$ in the summation.

Comment: @TheMathematician Yes. Fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: @nryyn I think the last case is not right for the function $\lim_{n \to \infty} sin(\frac{1}{n}) =0$.

Comment: @nryy I applied the example in case one and it worked.

Comment: @TheMathematician Which example?

Comment: I meant ln(n), but it was wrong too. The last case need another counterexample because sin 1/n is convergent when n goes to infinity.

Comment: @TheMathematician oh yes. I totally missed it. Thanks. I'll edit.